# SwiftUI programatic navigation loses binding

Tags: swiftui, data-binding, navigation

I'm building a "Charade-like-game" app with five screens and a simple `GameModel` class consisting of five objects, including teams, round, and scores.

**Screen1** dynamically determines the number of teams playing via `@StateObject`.

**Screen2** is a scoreboard that displays in a `VStack` the dynamic number of teams playing via `@ObservedObject`, alongside scores from two rounds of play.

**Screen3** shows the Charade criteria, and **Screen4** is a timer. Neither of these affect the `GameModel`.

**Screen5** gives the other teams a chance to score the performance. That value is then passed back to the **Screen2** scoreboard.

The navigation flow begins at 1 then moves to 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 then back to 2 to repeat the cycle until the users close the app, like this:

[image]

I got tangled up in the navigation because I wanted the back button on **Screen2** to start the game over, rather than return to **Screen5**. When I used `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` and `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`, it didn't navigate properly.

Therefore I tried building the navigation programmatically using a `@State` Boolean, to change the screen like this:

```
if playGamePressed {
    Screen2View()
} else {
    Screen1 code... 

    Select # of teams binded via @StateObject (my source of truth)

    Button(action: {
        playGamePressed = true
    } 
}
```

Now, the `@StateObject` binding no longer passes the dynamic number of teams. Everything worked prior to changing the navigation to programmatic.

I used this as a reference: [Swiftui nested navigation issue while using navigation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285696/swiftui-nested-navigation-issue-while-using-navigation-link), but the solution was `.presentationMode` that didn't work for me.

What am I missing?